# How to visualize time series in mm-yyyy format?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a problem with times series in R.
I have a df like this :

| date_article | occurences |
| --- | --- |
| 2020-12-01 | 1 |
| 2021-02-01 | 4 |
| 2021-01-01 | 3 |

I transform the df in order to convert date_article into date format :

```
df <- transform(df, date_article = as.Date(as.yearmon(date_article)))
```

After, I use ggplotly in order to visualise data :

```
# Usual area chart, pour le graphe
p <- df %>%
 ggplot( aes(x=date_article, y=occurences)) +
 geom_area(fill="#69b3a2", alpha=0.5) +
 geom_line(color="#69b3a2") +
 ylab("Indicateur EPU") +
 theme_ipsum()

 # Turn it interactive with ggplotly
 p <- ggplotly(p)
 p
```

Then I get the following graph :

[image: Graph]

In the x abscissa, I have this format when I put my cursor : 2020-11-01 and I would like to have something like : 2020-11, as yyyy-mm or mm-yyyy format.

I think the problem is when I transform my df into date format but I don't know how resolve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be achieved by making use of the `text` aesthetic to style the tooltip like so:

```
df <- read.table(text = "date_article   occurences
2020-12-01  1
2021-02-01  4
2021-01-01  3", header = TRUE)

library(plotly)
library(hrbrthemes)
library(zoo)

df <- transform(df, date_article = as.Date(as.yearmon(date_article)))

df %>%
  ggplot( aes(x=date_article, y=occurences, 
              text = paste0("date_article: ", format(date_article, "%Y-%m"), "\n",
                            "occurences: ", occurences), group = 1)) +
  geom_area(fill="#69b3a2", alpha=0.5) +
  geom_line(color="#69b3a2") +
  ylab("Indicateur EPU") +
  theme_ipsum()

# Turn it interactive with ggplotly
ggplotly(tooltip = "text")
```

[image]